# Laravel form request not updating nullable field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-validation

I have created a PostRequest in Laravel (using `php artisan make:request PostRequest`). I have three columns: title, content, and tag). The tag column is nullable. When I add some posts there is no problem, I am able to add title, content, and tag.

However, when I want to edit a post, the title and content column change but the tag column is not. How can handle this?

**Controller**

```
public function update(PostRequest $request, Post $post)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();

    Post::whereId($post->id)->update($validated);

    return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'success');
}
```

**PostRequest.php**

```
public function rules()
{
    switch ($this->method()) {
        case 'POST':
        {
            return [
                'title' => 'required|max:512',
                'content' => 'required',
            ];
        }
        case 'PUT':
        case 'PATCH':
        {
            return [
                'title' => 'required|max:512',
                'content' => 'required',
            ];
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**Post.php (model)**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'content',
    'tag',
    'created_at',
];
```

Comment: The form request only returns the fields you defined. If you want `tag` to return, create a validation rule in your `PostRequest`

Answer (score 3):

You are using `$request->validated()` that filters your request inputs and returns only validated fields. So adding a new rule for `tag` will fix your issue:

```php
return [
    'title' => 'required|max:512',
    'content' => 'required',
    'tag' => 'nullable'
];
```